# Create a button to control the JavaScript create some elements. Then if any of these element changes, do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create a button using HTML. If user click the button, then use javascript to create some elements (like checkboxes). After these, if any of the elements changes, do something, like printing out some text.
Following is my code.

HTML:

```
<button id="try" type="button">TRY</button>
<div id="boxes"></div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
doit = function(){
var checkboxes = "";
for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){
   checkboxes += "<input type='checkbox' name='a'/>Option" + i+"<br>";
}
$("#boxes").html(checkboxes);
}

$('#try').click(function(){
    doit();
})

$("input[name='a']").on("change",function(){
    $("#demo").text("success!")
})
```

I really can't figure out where I am wrong. **Demo:**https://jsfiddle.net/slfan/cu7tn64o/12/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dynamically adding new elements, you need to use a delegate event handler:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name='a']", function() {
  $("#demo").text("success!")
})
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cu7tn64o/14/

Comment: Thank you. So why other handler exist if we already have the delegate handler?

Comment: like the one I was writing. The JQUERY. Sorry I'm very new to jacascript.

Comment: It's more of a different pattern rather than functionality. See https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html